# Applet Components Go To Default Layout After Switching Tabs

Tags: java, applet

I used setLocation(x, y) to place components in an AWT-based applet, but when I switch tabs the positions of the components go back to their default layout.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AppletEx extends Applet {

  Label test;

  public void init() {

      test = new Label("test");
      add(test);   

  }

  public void start() {
  }

  public void stop() {
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }

  public void paint() {
      test.setLocation(10, 10);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
// it is the 3rd millennium, time to use Swing
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

/** <applet code='AppletEx' width='120' height='50'></applet> */
public class AppletEx extends JApplet {

  JLabel test;

  public void init() {
      test = new JLabel("test");
      // a border can be used for component padding
      test.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
      // default layout of Applet is FlowLayout,
      // while JApplet is BorderLayout
      add(test, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
  }
}
```

Other tips.

- Don't try to create or change any component inside `paint()` it will cause a loop.
- Don't override `paint()` unless doing custom painting.
- Don't override `paint()` in a top level container like `Applet` or `Frame`, but in something like a `Panel` or `JPanel` that can be added to it.
- ***Use layouts***  (as opposed to that nonsense of a `null` layout).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use absolute positioning, you need to not use a layout manager:

```
setLayout(null);
test = new Label("test");
add(test);
test.setLocation(10, 10);
test.setSize(test.getPreferredSize());
```